# B1/B2 visa granted without annotations

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas

What does it mean when my approved B1/B2 US visa has no annotations indicated even though I told in the interview that I will be taking my exam in Guam?

Comment: What annotation would you have expected and why?

Answer (score 6):

From the US Foreign Affairs Manual ([9 FAM 403.9 NIV [nonimmigrant visa] ISSUANCES](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040309.html)):

> 9 FAM 403.9-5(A)  (U) Annotating Visas
>
> (CT:VISA-1762;   04-27-2023)
>
> a. (U) Annotating visas is a useful tool that can help both the visa holder and immigration inspectors at ports of entry (POEs).  In many circumstances, the Foreign Affairs Manual (FAM) requires you to annotate visas. Annotations also provide CA and others (through the CCD) with information, both current and historical.  It may be the only way in which certain information is collected in an electronic format.  Understanding when to annotate and when not to annotate a visa, and what information should or must be included, is important in making annotations effective.
>
> b. (U) A visa annotation is a simple and useful method to convey information about a visa applicant and the circumstances under which a visa was issued, explain the circumstances or assumptions on which the visa decision was based, or clarify key factors which were considered at the time of adjudication.  The information contained in a visa annotation should help facilitate an immigration inspector’s decision on whether to admit the visa holder to the United States, and, if to admit, for how long.  See 9 FAM 402.3-4(H).
>
> c.  (U) Annotations should be concise and should be understandable to persons outside the Department.  Abbreviations may be used, but they must be clear and self-evident.  You should not use jargon or shorthand.  Annotations should always be constructive and informative.  You should carefully review annotations to avoid conveying a negative tone.

Following this, there are several sections discussing certain annotations for specific visa types, including B-1 but not including B-2.  The B-1 annotations mostly concern special applications of that visa class.

The section on tourists and business visitors, [9 FAM 402.2](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040202.html), has some additional information about annotations for B visas.

The conclusion from all of this is that nothing about your application triggered a requirement for the consular officer to add an annotation, and the consular officer did not find it necessary to "convey information about [you or] the circumstances under which [your] visa was issued, explain the circumstances or assumptions on which the visa decision was based, or clarify key factors which were considered at the time of adjudication."

In other words, there was nothing unusual about your application, so you got a standard 10-year visa that you can continue to use whenever you want to visit the US over the next 10 years, as long as the purpose of each visit is allowable in B-1 or B-2 status.

Answer (score 3):

if it is approved, then you are good to go. ignore the absence of annotations